# How to install a custom PHP extension that depends on a static library

Tags: php-extension

I've looked around (most relevant [was this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187017/php-extension-with-custom-c-library).)

I wrote a custom php extension to wrap a static lib (built with PGI.)

It wasn't straight forward, but in general:

- Downloaded PHP source
- Wrote the extension using tutorials
- export LDFLAGS="-L/home/matt/fstd_php/php-src/ext/fstd/lib -L/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2012/libso"
- export LIBS="-lrmn -lpgf90 -lpghpf2 -lpgf90rtl -lpgftnrtl -lpghpf_rpm -lpgc -lrt -lm"
- Built PHP with the extension, it works

Is there any way I can use this in a pre-installed version of PHP on Ubuntu?

The module is named fstd

I tried mimicking how other modules are installed (arbitrarily chose mongo), so I added an ini file in /etc/php5/mods-available, then added the .so I found in ext/fstd/modules/fstd.so into /usr/lib/php5/20100525/

Didn't seem to work though with the system install of php.

So I enabled_dl in php.ini, and tried to include the .so.  It doesn't seem to include the dependant libraries.  I get:

```
matt@khea ...php-src/ext/fstd % php -f fstd.php
PHP Warning:  dl(): Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20100525/fstd.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20100525/fstd.so: undefined symbol: c_fstfrm in /home/matt/fstd_php/php-src/ext/fstd/fstd.php on line 5
```

The symbol c_fstfrm is a symbol in the static library I'm trying to wrap.

So, is there a proper way to install this as a system module/extension?  Otherwise, to use custom extensions, must I have to only use a version of php and extensions that I build myself?

Comment: Isn't this problem a more genera Linux libraries path issue, like [this one](http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=4736)?

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to figure this out, so instead I built PHP as a CGI and only use it where needed (rather than doing anything to the system php install)